# Angularjs and burp suite

Tags: angularjs, suite, burp

One of my client says he could see html and javascript using burp suite. we have used angularjs in client side and serverside we used webapi.

He says he should not see sensitive data in html pages. may i know what would be the solution for this.

Comment: I guess you need to minify and uglify the javascript files.

Comment: HTML can be minify as well, but it doesn't protect your data. If you put sensitive data in the HTML, move it to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the JavaScript and HTML files are those data supposed to be sent to user. **So if you have any sensitive data that should not be disclosed to the user, simply do not include them in the JavaScript and HTML.**

As a best practice, to protect your client-side business logic (and improve the page loading performance), usually recomended is to [uglify](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) and [minify](https://javascript-minifier.com/) your JavaScript files. In such a way, they become human unreadable.

But please keep in mind that, uglifying does not kind of encrypt your data. For example, if you want to show your bank account balance on the page, there may be a JavaScript variable `bankAccountBalance=100` could be renamed to be `b=100` (so unreadable by human), but its value is always be the real number in your bank account, i.e., `100`.

[HTML can be minified as well](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier) (And it should be). But it just helps to remove line breaks, extra space, etc. It is not protecting your data.

Comment: in html page we have used {{ }} expression and ngbind some thing like this {{x.sno}}. so the client says it is sensitive information we should not show in burp suite and i want to let you know the data sent and rececived from server is encripted.Is this really a sensitive information do we have any security issues.

Comment: From my knowledge, it is not a security issue. What I can recommend to persuade the client: 1. rename the variables to be different from the field names in the database; 2. use `ng-cloak` or `ng-bind` (not `{{}}`) to prevent showing `{{}}` to the end users.